# Creating a Cron Job for daily application backup (2 scripts needed?)

Tags: scripting, cron, backups

I have an application where I manually go in and back up certain files(1), and manually copy those files via WinSCP(2).

I would like to be able to use two scripts/ cron jobs to automate these tasks.

Here are the steps/commands I use to back up the files:

```
    sudo as admin
    cd to directory
    export PATH=$PATH:/<filePath>/
    ./export-<appData.sh Backups/ /<filePath>/
```

Once that is complete, I will login to WINSCP and look in the directory where the data is backed up.  I copy them over to the Backups shared directory manually.

Any help with creating a script/cron job to automate this process would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shared drive in windows that can be accessible through sambha in linux ; then make a script that can copy from your linux server to windows server.

I hope this will be useful.